# Vimeo API and sub account allocation in a web application

Tags: vimeo-api

Is it possible to use Vimeo API to get payment from a person and allocate to sub  accounts based on a priority algorithm on a webapp?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Did you do any research on Vimeo API?

Answer (score 1):

No. We do not support purchasing through our API right now.